# Include XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have the following working xml layout for a ListView

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text01"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/widget02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget01"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to move text01 and all RelativeLayout in another file (it is the header for all my activities) and include it in this xml. I am trying but I am not able to do this, can sameone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You should put the things you want to reuse into extra files. Then you can use the parts like:

```
<!-- my_header.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text01"/>
```

In another file include it with:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_header" />
<!-- your other stuff -->
```

Comment: Simply moving code to my_header I have the following errors:

 - error: Error parsing XML: unbound 
  prefix
 - error: Error parsing XML: no 
  element found
 - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
  formed.
  
I think there are same more tag to add to included file. I try to add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> but errors remain

Comment: you need to put the xml-header of course. I updated my answer

Comment: @Stuck: For accuracy it would be better if you use the <!-- --> XML comment format to avoid potential confusion.

Comment: the problem remain, I think error is caused from the lack of a layout typology definition at the beginning of included file, is it possible?

Comment: Solved :-) included fill have to begin with <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Comment: it must not. But maybe in your situation. :-) please accept answer

Answer (score 0):

First : create a new file layout xml : **header.xml** ; which will contain the TextView and all the RelativeLayout

Second : you can include it where ever you want  with the following code :

```
<include android:id="@+id/myHeader" 
     layout="@layout/header" />
```